# fread issue with integer64

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I am trying to read in some larger datafiles in R with `fread` using `integer64="numeric"`, but for some reason the conversion does not work anywhere (it used to work in the past). Some of my outcome data is in `integer`, some is in `integer64` and some is in `numeric`. That is probably not intended. The problem seems to be known: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2607

My question is: What is the best current workaround to deal with this? If someone has an idea how to post sample data to illustrate the issue more clearly, please feel free to contribute to this post.

I guess this affects a lot of people who are using numbers >= |2^31|. Also see the documentation of fread in this regard: "integer64" (default) reads columns detected as containing integers larger than 2^31 as type bit64::integer64. Alternatively, "double"|"numeric" reads as base::read.csv does; i.e., possibly with loss of precision and if so silently. Or, "character".

Comment: Can you read with `integer64="character"` and then coerce to numeric once it's in memory?

Comment: @MattSummersgill thanks, but that doesn't work. I still get some columns which are `int` or `integer64` besides `chr`, to be more precise, it is the same columns which are `int` or `integer64` in the case when I was using `integer64="numeric"`. So the problem seems to be as follows: Some columns have numbers below |2^31|, which are designated as `int`. Some other columns have numbers above |2^31|, which are (correctly) designated as `chr`. And some columns have numbers far beyond |2^31| (e.g. with a max value of 24091070278), which are designated as `integer64`.

Comment: Additional Q from my side: Is it safe to read in as any of the above classes and convert into numeric then afterwards, manually?